# Oracle Apex : How to get the URL requested?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex 19.2 application.

I'm trying to log in the database all the pages requested of my application.

I created an Application Process that runs **On load Before the header** on all the pages that saves the page requested in a table.

So far, I can get the AppId, the PageId and the Session that I store in a table :

```
insert into PAGESVISITED 
(Application, PAGE, IPAdress, UserAgent, Session) 
values 
(:APP_ID, :APP_PAGE_ID, owa_util.get_cgi_env('X-FORWARDED-FOR'), owa_util.get_cgi_env('user-agent'), :APP_SESSION));
```

I would like to know please if there is a way to get the entire URL requested. Means including the pages items set as well their values.

When we know the Page Item set in a URL, It's easy to get its value. But is it possible to get any Page Item name and its value for a generic page ? or any way to get the entire url requested for example get :

```
f?p=App:Page:Session:Request:Debug:ClearCache:itemNames:itemValues:PrinterFriendly
```

I'm not asking how to use the function **APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL** to generate a URL. My question is more : assuming a URL requested, how to get all its details ?

Thank you in advance.
Cheers,

[image]

Comment: Most of the info is captured in apex_activity_log by default - you could consider copying it from that view on a daily basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer :

```
OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env('X-Original-URL')
```

Actually a lot of information can be extracted using :

```
OWA_UTIL.print_cgi_env;
```